# Postman - Get only endpoint from a URL

Tags: javascript, postman

Having this kind of endpoing:

https://hey.com/p1/m/p2

I want to get rid of the `https://hey.com` and get only the `/p1/m/p2` part on the *Pre-request Script*. I know I can do it using `request.url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '')`, getting the desired output `/p1/m/p2`.

Is there any other way to do it without using replace or regex? Something like `request.url.pathname` (which is not working, obviously).

The URL above is just an example, the endpoints and urls will vary.

Bear in mind that I'm using the *Pre-request Script* on the Postman environment and some things may not work.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) browser API to construct a URL object.

```
(new URL(request.url)).pathname
```

If you're using the desktop version, you can use the built-in node.js API.

```
var URL = require('url');

URL.parse(request.url).pathname
```

Comment: Hi Ben. I get the following error: _ReferenceError: URL is not defined_

Comment: Just in case someone else wants to get the parameters along with the _pathname_, use this: `URL.parse(request.url).pathname + URL.parse(request.url).search`

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this

```
var fullUrl = request.url.split('/');
fullUrl.splice(0,3);
var url = a.join('/');
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Can you please give me the reason to downvote ? It will help me to improve my future posts. i have tried this in postman and it is working.So hopefully it is not due to that

Comment: Hi, Deniver! I was looking for a _smarter_ solution rather than using a _replace_ or _regex_ as I stated on the post. Your solution dones't improve the one I proposed, it's just string replacement and that's what I don't want to do. The answer of Ben is what I was looking for.